# Flutter: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, plugins, timeago

I want to get TimeStamp from mysql & Change it into time ago
My TimeStamp is look like:

```
2021-03-04 06:06:48
```

And in Flutter:

```
[{id: 1, caption: first post, useruid: b0zbRHZEKMbGSdNoVSjI0gsxXTX2, time: 2021-03-04 06:06:48,}],
```

Error
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'

Here i call to change my date & time to timeago with the help of this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/timeago)..

```
ListView(
        children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>((document) {
      Provider.of<PostFunctions>(context, listen: false)
          .showTimeAgo(document['time']);
return My Other Code...
)


I show like this in My Text
```

```
' , ${Provider.of<PostFunctions>(context, listen: false).getImageTimePosted.toString()}'
```

I Change my Date&Time Here

```
  showTimeAgo(dynamic timedata) {
    print(timedata);

    imageTimePosted = timeago.format(timedata);
    print(' my time posted ***** $imageTimePosted');
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You probably need to use `DateTime.tryParse()` method to convert your String into a DateTime since the package use a DateTime and you're giving a String by doing as follow:

```dart
showTimeAgo(document['time']);
```

Make this change:

```dart
showTimeAgo(DateTime.tryParse(document['time']));
```